# Kubernetes nodes are idle, but Out of cpu error when scheduling pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have multiple nodes, which are lying mostly idle, but getting an error while scheduling pods/services saying "Insufficient CPU"

Node usage output :-

```
top - 17:59:45 up 17 days,  2:52,  1 user,  load average: 5.61, 7.85, 8.58
Tasks: 2030 total,   3 running, 1771 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  6.5 us,  2.3 sy,  0.4 ni, 90.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 39616812+total, 29776403+free, 30507960 used, 67896128 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 35842112+avail Mem
```

As it can be seen, whole bunch of memory/cpu is lying idle (~ 80 to 90 % is free)

Same can be confirmed by the fact :-

```
$ kubectl top nodes
W0615 14:03:16.457271     108 top_node.go:119] Using json format to get metrics. Next release will switch to protocol-buffers, switch early by passing --use-protocol-buffers flag
NAME     CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
node1    4680m        29%    14943Mi         47%
node10   9524m        19%    44735Mi         11%
node11   273m         0%     1614Mi          0%
node12   289m         0%     1617Mi          0%
node2    1736m        10%    11683Mi         37%
node3    3223m        20%    17837Mi         56%
node4    1680m        10%    15075Mi         47%
node5    7386m        15%    39163Mi         10%
node6    5392m        22%    26448Mi         20%
node7    2457m        5%     28002Mi         7%
node8    4853m        10%    51863Mi         13%
node9    3620m        7%     18299Mi         4%
```

But when scheduling pods, getting an error (kubectl describe pod POD_NAME) :-

```
Events:
Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
----     ------            ----  ----               -------
Warning  FailedScheduling  62m   default-scheduler  0/12 nodes are available: 5 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 7 Insufficient cpu.
```

The reason I understand why this is happening is (kubectl descibe node node10) :-

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests          Limits
  --------           --------          ------
  cpu                47887m (99%)      92270m (192%)
  memory             59753371Ki (15%)  87218649344 (21%)
  ephemeral-storage  2Gi (0%)          2Gi (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)            0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)            0 (0%)
```

The pods have allocated all of the cpu resources across all the nodes

Even though the actual usage is very low, k8s thinks the nodes are fully occupied.
What I am trying to achieve is how to overcommit the resources ?
I tried editing "Allocatable" cpu 2x times the "Capacity", but changes don't persist.
Any suggestion how can I overcommit ?

Comment: Read up on pod resource requests/limits. The scheduler uses requests & limits, not actual resource utilization.

Comment: can you add output of `kubectl get pod <podname> -o yaml`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot overcommit on requests, as those form the minimum required resources for a given pod to run. You can overcommit on limits, as you can see by your `192%` there.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the only way to accommodate more pods / make node more useful is make the pods have smaller Requests (irrespective of Limits), or remove the REQUEST at all to have unlimited access to cpu, or clean up the stale pods/services ?

Comment: Technically sure? The memory and CPU request on a pod should be the minimum required for normal functioning. If those are not set correctly then yes you should update them. But if they are set correctly then you need more hardware :)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, going forward for the time being we won't setting request at all, and will be setting up nagios alerts to monitor the node activity. Thanks again

Comment: That is inadvisable. You should set them to at least minimum reasonable values.

Comment: @Alceatraz Fix your requests to better reflect reality.

Comment: @coderanger The problem is: Those yaml not write by myself, And some project using CDR-config and controller, Their controller install component by CDR. Modify request is impossible.

Comment: I think you mean "CRD" and you can just not use that operator. Or fork it. Or write a mutating admission controller. Lots of options, I'm sure you'll figure it out :)